How to avoid wildcard SSL at root domain overriding a subdomain SSL?
I have a root domain example.com from IONOS and I’ve mapped its subdomain www.example.com to a Google Cloud Run instance. Since GCP cloud run supports custom domain mapping and provides an SSL, everything works fine for that www subdomain.
Now I want to redirect my root domain to the www subdomain, IIUC this requires my root domain to also have an SSL. The IONOS indeed provides a free wildcard SSL, but how do I make sure it won’t override the google-managed SSL in the subdomain? (Because IIUC I cannot have 2 SSL cover the same subdomain as it may cause certificate mismatch?)
Here are the research I’ve done and their problems:

Don’t use google SSL. Instead use google https load balancer with my own wildcard SSL. I don’t want to use this solution because it incurs extra cost for the load balancer.
Also set up the cloud run instance to link to the root domain. But this doesn’t work as cloud run can only map to sub domain.


"Because IIUC I cannot have 2 SSL cover the same subdomain as it may cause certificate mismatch?" - you can. This would make your question obsolete since it is based on wrong assumptions. Marked as duplicate of a question which explains why you can have multiple certificates covering the same domain.
